# How to get sum & latest activity in same result?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

```
Table_1
Name   |   Activity  | LogTime
A      |    0        | 2018-12-17 10:16:04.877 
A      |    1        | 2018-12-15 10:16:04.877
A      |    0        | 2018-12-16 10:16:04.877
A      |    0        | 2018-12-10 10:16:04.877
A      |    0        | 2018-12-10 10:10:04.877
B      |    1        | 2018-12-16 10:16:04.877
B      |    0        | 2018-12-17 10:16:04.877
C      |    1        | 2018-12-14 10:16:04.877
C      |    1        | 2018-12-12 10:16:04.877
C      |    1        | 2018-12-18 10:16:04.877
```

Desired Result

```
Name |   TOTALActivity_0  | TOTALActivity_1  |  LatestActivity_0_Logtime  | LatestActivity_1_Logtime
A    |      4             |     1            |  2018-12-17 10:16:04.877   |  2018-12-15 10:16:04.877
B    |      1             |     1            |  2018-12-17 10:16:04.877   |  2018-12-16 10:16:04.877
C    |      0             |     3            |  NULL                      |  2018-12-18 10:16:04.877
```

I am able to get result as below

```
Name |   TOTALActivity_0  | TOTALActivity_1
A    |      4             |     1          
B    |      1             |     1          
C    |      0             |     3
```

Using below query

```
SELECT 
  NAME, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTALActivity_0,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTALActivity_1
 FROM Table_1
 GROUP BY NAME
```

If I tried as below

```
 SELECT 
  NAME, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTALActivity_0,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTALActivity_1,
  CASE WHEN Activity = 0 THEN LogTime ELSE NULL END AS LatestActivity_0_Logtime,
  CASE WHEN Activity = 1 THEN LogTime ELSE NULL END AS LatestActivity_1_Logtime
 FROM Table_1
 GROUP BY NAME,Activity,LogTime
```

Then it is giving Single-single & redundant records.
Then I tried with again with below query

```
 SELECT 
  NAME, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTALActivity_0,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTALActivity_1,
  NULL AS LatestActivity_0_Logtime,
  NULL AS LatestActivity_1_Logtime
 FROM Table_1
 GROUP BY NAME
 UNION
 SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,CASE WHEN Activity = 0 THEN LogTime ELSE NULL END AS LatestActivity_0_Logtime,
  CASE WHEN Activity = 1 THEN LogTime ELSE NULL END AS LatestActivity_1_Logtime
  FROM Table_1
```

Then result is again undesirable as below

```
Name |   TOTALActivity_0  | TOTALActivity_1  |  LatestActivity_0_Logtime  | LatestActivity_1_Logtime
A    |      4             |     1            |  NULL                      |  NULL
B    |      1             |     1            |  NULL                      |  NULL
B    |      1             |     3            |  NULL                      |  NULL  
NULL |     NULL           |   NULL           |  2018-12-17 10:16:04.877   |  2018-12-15 10:16:04.877
NULL |     NULL           |   NULL           |  2018-12-16 10:16:04.877   |  2018-12-16 10:16:04.877
NULL |     NULL           |   NULL           |  2018-12-10 10:16:04.877   |  2018-12-18 10:16:04.877   
NULL |     NULL           |   NULL           |  2018-12-10 10:10:04.877   |  2018-12-15 10:16:04.877
NULL |     NULL           |   NULL           |  2018-12-17 10:16:04.877   |  2018-12-16 10:16:04.877
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Please Help to get distinct & merged result as desired

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Activity = 0 THEN 1 END) AS TOTALActivity_0,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Activity = 1 THEN 1 END) AS TOTALActivity_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 0 THEN LogTime END) AS LatestActivity_0_Logtime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 1 THEN LogTime END) AS LatestActivity_1_Logtime
FROM
    Table_1
GROUP BY
    Name ;
```

Test in: **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6316c4c77af2ad185ad4fb101b7e218)**

Comment: Wow, I tried using function which was obviously not optimal. Great,thanks